# How to put two cck fields in add content page in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, cck

I have created a content type in Drupal 6.

I want to add an input field to a number and a select(dropdown) field to get Year/months. They should be next to each other in add content page.

User enters for example 3 months by typing 3 in text input and select months from dropdown. But I don't know can I do it in Druapl 6 using CCK.

If I add two fields they will be shown with their label but I want they be next to each other without any label between them.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use either "CCK 3.0 module" and group the fields together and this is the simplest solution but you ll have the label unfortunately ."http://drupal.org/project/cck" .

Or another solution is to make your own custom cck field with their widgets and here's the links to help you ...
http://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/creating-custom-cck-fields

http://darcynorman.net/2008/05/02/creating-a-custom-compound-field-for-cck/

Comment: Now I have CCK 2.9, and have some content types which have cck fields. How can I update CCK 2.9 to CCK 3.0 ?

Comment: i think replace the old module with the new one " folders" and then call update.php of drupal .. it will run any changes